ASP.Net MVC - no file content uploaded
There is a simple functionality:

HTML page with dropzone.js (or jQuery Upload plugin, I tried several ways).
MVC controller method:


    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveDoc(string docName, Guid docType, HttpPostedFileBase docFile)
    {
        if (docFile == null)
        {
            docFile = Request.Files[0];    
        }
        byte[] bytes = new byte[docFile.ContentLength];
        using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(docFile.InputStream))
        {
            bytes = reader.ReadBytes(docFile.ContentLength);
        }
        ///
        /// The rest of saving procedure 
        ///
        return View();
    }

As it is seen, there is a need to check if HttpPostedFileBase object is null. Sometimes this object does not contain file but the file can be read in Request.Files.
Generally it works ok but logger shows there is a very rare error occurs once per hundred or more uploads. The error of "nocontent file upload". I divide them into 2 parts:

"Blob"-type


    HttpPostedFileBase is null,
    HttpRequestBase.ContentLength: 544
    HttpRequestBase.Form: docName=Doc+Name&docType=0d76cedb-327e-4084-bb5f-5315d2c7f71a
    HttpRequestBase.Files: 1,
    HttpRequestBase.Files\[0\].ContentLength: 0,
    HttpRequestBase.Files\[0\].ContentType: application/octet-stream,
    HttpRequestBase.Files\[0\].FileName: blob,
    Header Content-Length: 544

As far as you can see, the name of file is set to "blob", the length of file is 0, but Content-Length header is 544 (in some cases it varies but always between 500-600)
2. "Fake"-type

    HttpPostedFileBase: null
    HttpRequestBase.ContentLength: 479765
    HttpRequestBase.Form: docName=Doc+Name+1&docTypeId=0d76cedb-327e-4084-bb5f-5315d2c7f71a
    HttpRequestBase.Files: 0
    Header Content-Length: 479765

Here it is seen, that Request.Files does not contain the file, while content length of Request shows there IS a content of file.
Noone error can be replicated or emulated, they occur only with remote users. Changing the upload mechanism (I used various plugins and different setting) - no real change, the errors appear by the same frequency. "Blob" error, seems, related to attempt of file-upload plugin to send file by chunks, but even plugins without this functionality cause this problem and plugins like dropzone.js, being configured with huge minimum limit of chinking and even prohibiting chunking, still cause this problem.
Any idea which direction shall I look to find the solution ?
PS: There is a statistics of error, showing that 97% of errors occurred when sending file from mobile device (Android or iOS), but the rest 3% - Windows and MacOs, so - there is no strict dependency.
